# Python callback handlers- better error messages?

Tags: python, json, error-handling, stomp, traceback

I'm using the [stomp.py](http://code.google.com/p/stomppy/) library to get JSON messages from over a network. I've adapted the simple example they give [here](http://code.google.com/p/stomppy/wiki/SimpleExample) which uses a callback to provide message handling.

But I made a simple error when I modified that callback- for example, I called json.load() instead of json.loads() when trying to parse my JSON string.

```
class MyListener(object):
    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        data = json.load(message)           ## Should be .loads() for a string!
```

Usually that would be fine- it would AttributeError and I'd see a traceback. But in this case Python prints:

**No handlers could be found for logger "stomp.py"**

... no traceback, no crash out, and that was all. Very confusing to debug and find out what I did wrong! I was expecting at least the normal traceback along the lines of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ncl/stomp.py-3.1.3/stompJSONParser.py", line 32, in <module>
    [etc etc ...]
```

... rather than it borking the whole listener. I guess it's because that happens on a different thread?

Now that I've worked out it's like a kind of runtime error in the callback I at least know I've done something wrong when it errors- but if it just spews that error for every mistake I make rather than giving me some kind of useful message, it makes it a bit difficult to code.

What causes this? And what could I do to **get the regular, more verbose traceback back**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like its expecting a log handler from the [Python Logging Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to be set up in order to capture output. There are lots of possible configurations for logging. But for simple debugging I would use something along the lines of

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

That should capture all output of log level DEBUG and above. Read the logging docs for more info :)

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for getting a logger (which is what is being asked for directly) can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), but the verbose traceback is suppressed.

If you take a look at the [code which is calling `on_message`](https://code.google.com/p/stomppy/source/browse/stomp/connect.py), you'll notice that that block is in a `try` block without an `except`.

Line 703 is where the method is actually called:

```
        notify_func = getattr(listener, 'on_%s' % frame_type)
        notify_func(headers, body)
```

which is in method `__notify` (declared on line 639):

```
def __notify(self, frame_type, headers=None, body=None):
```

These are the times when it is not in a try block:

- 331 (for the `connected` event)
- 426 for the `send` event
- 743 for `disconnected`

But the time when `message` is called is line 727:

```
# line 719
try:
    # ....
    self.__notify(frame_type, headers, body)
```

Comment: @Inks Sorry I had to give bad news.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I grabbed the logger by name and set a StreamHandler on it:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('stomp.py')
strh = logging.StreamHandler()
strh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
log.addHandler(strh);
```